# Project needs to be opened by Visual Studio 2008 by default in Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8

I have installed visual studio 2008 and 2010 and also vs 2012 on windows 8. Now if I open a vs 2008 project, it asks me to convert it to vs 2010 which I don't want.

In windows 8 I tried "open with" but I can't see vs 2008 in programs, when i go to it's destination and try to open it, it opens up as VS 2010 again.

**Update**

***Problem isn't that i can't open projects with VS 2008, problem is I am not able to force a VS 2008 solution to be opened by VS 2008 (by default).
I can open the project by opening VS 2008 and then use file -> Open
These projects are in SVN Tortoise Repository, on windows 7 they open by VS 2008 by default but now I got windows 8 so each time I open project, it asks me for this,***

[image]

**Sorry for confusion.**

Comment: Open VS2008 and then use the `File` menu to open it?

Comment: ^^ I am already doing this, but I am tired of doing it again and again

Comment: go to solution file-->right click-->properties--->check if there is option of change--->select application which you want to open with,it had work for me in windows 7 as my all projects were opening in vb6-default then i tried this

Comment: From the Modern UI Start screen, search Settings for "Make a file type always open in a specific program".

Comment: Was this project already opened in a later version of VS and migrated? Look for a ChangeLog of some kind, or you can probably open the `.*proj` or `*.sln` files and see if it's looking for a specific VS instance.

Comment: Nope, these are VS 2008 solutions in SVN Tortoise repository, when I open them they open in VS 2010 by default and ask for solution conversion wizard

Comment: @user13814: I'm assuming it's a dependancy that vs2008 can't handle so it's handing it off. There should be no reason why you can't run VS2008 stand-alone and not able to just file-open. was this a project you worked on previously and now it just won't open with vs2008? or did you get a new machine and can't get it to act like it was? (i guess I'm assuming this worked before and asking what has changed)

Comment: If I double-click the .vcproj file, it starts VS 2012 Converson Wizard.  But if I double-click the .sln file, it starts VS 2008.  So make sure you are double-clicking the .sln file.

Comment: I have been clicking  .sln file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it's working the way it use to work in Windows 7 but I will look it into it, however I am able to fix the problem by,

[image]

I think problem came up because I installed VS 2012 and VS 2010 first and then installed VS 2008 at end.

Comment: That's the default file association.  A more interesting answer would explain how it got screwed up in the first place.  Or why mouse clicking like this is "better" than just pressing Ctrl+Shift+O.

Comment: I will need to dig deep for that, but I updated my answer, will keep looking why it happened

Answer (score 1):

I am experienced something similar.

Windows 8.1 with VS2008 and VS2013 installed.

Problem:

1. Right mouse select a VS2008 .sln file in File manager.
2. Select "Open with..." from the menu
3. The dialog shows one choice, VS2013.
4. From the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog, select "More Options"
5. Scroll down past all the new choices and select "Look for another app on this PC"
6. Paste in the path to VS2008.  Example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
7. It runs VS2013 instead.

Also, using "File->Properties" to associate the .sln file with VS2008 did not work as I expected. After setting the file association, I expected the be able to double click on that .sln file and bring up VS2008 but it ran VS2013 instead.

Solution:

After using "File->Properties" to attempt to associate the .sln file with VS2008 something has changed.
Now when I attempt step 2 ("Open with..") I get 2 choices: VS2013 and "Visual Studio Version Selector". Selecting "Version Selector" with "Use the App for all .sln files" checked will cause subsequent .sln files to be opened with the correct Visual Studio.